# message.success not showing message django

Tags: python, django

I'm new to django, I have been trying to display success message when an user successfully adds an project.I'm using message.success but it doesn't seem to work.I have used the same thing in my other apps but there it works don't know why it doesn't work in this case.
Views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import views
from .forms import project_form
from django.shortcuts import render,redirect,HttpResponse
from apps.profiles.models import profiles
from django.contrib import messages

class Add_project(views.View):
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    loggeduser=profiles.objects.get(Username__username=request.user)
    return render(
    request,
    'form.html',
    context={
        'form': project_form(initial={"by_username":loggeduser})
    }
    )

def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
    form=project_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        messages.success(request,('Project saved successfully'))
        return redirect('projects:AddProject')
       # projects.objects.get(by_username__username=request.user)

    else:
        return HttpResponse(
            '''
            <html><body><h1>Not valid'''
            )
```

form.html

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{error}}
        {{ form }}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul class="messages">
        {% for message in messages %}
        <li class="{{ message.tags }}">{{ message }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import Add_project,project_list
urlpatterns = [
path('addproject/',Add_project.as_view(),name='AddProject'),
]
```

When redirected the page displays form perfectly but the message doesn't appear.Help me out please.

Comment: I don't see an obvious problem here, but check your project settings that you have taken all the steps listed here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/messages/#enabling-messages

Comment: that's what I don't understand whats the problem here,all the settings are according to django docs.Infact when I redirect to another page the messages are displayed there,but not on this particular 'form.html' page. @RobinZigmond

Comment: You mean you want the message to (very briefly) flash onto the screen as soon as the form is submitted, before the redirect? I'm afraid that's not how the messages framework works, it gets added to the context of the *next* request. There's no way to achieve what you seem to want without Javascript - and it wouldn't be a great idea because the message would likely not be there long enough for the user to read it before the redirect happens.

Comment: I want it to be displayed on redirected page along with other contents of the page @RobinZigmond

Comment: I'm really confused. So the problem is that the page redirects as intended, but doesn't display the message? That is what you say in the OP, but in your first comment above you say "the messages are displayed", so I need to be clear on this.

Answer (score 0):

I was also stuck with such an issue. I wanted to make custom message, but nothing happened.

Eventually, there're 2 ways which I've found:

1. If you want to overwrite `post` method, then it's possible to use standard `message.success/warning etc`. I did it as wanted to delete posts from `ListView`.

```sh
    else:
        post.delete()
        messages.success(request, f"{', '.join([str(x) for x in result])} removed")
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

2. Second way is simple return from `get_success_message`. Here customization is limited, but at least something can be done.

```sh
    def get_success_message(self, cleaned_data):
        return 'Post was updated'
```

Also don't forget to add `SuccessMessageMixin` to the class.

And if you want to do it without CBV (class based views), then it's plain:

```sh
messages.success(request, f"{new_user}のアカウントがされた！")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
form=project_form(request.POST)
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
    messages.success(self.request,'Project saved successfully')
    return redirect('projects:AddProject')
   # projects.objects.get(by_username__username=request.user)

else:
    return HttpResponse(
        '''
        <html><body><h1>Not valid'''
        )
```

Add self.request to your messages.success